# Reducing Package Dependencies in .net core/standard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, csproj

I'm trying to upgrade some libraries I've built in VS2015/.net core to VS2017. While the project.json > *.csproj conversion went fairly well, I'm having troubles trying to make my library(ies) not depend on the full framework but only on the packages I really need.

What I previously did was documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/reducing-dependencies

That was working fine. After the upgrade, my "Dependencies" has the SDK nuget installed and it can't be removed.

Project.csproj contains the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyTitle>DDS.Core.Commons.Annotations</AssemblyTitle>
        <VersionPrefix>17.03.08.1526</VersionPrefix>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net46</TargetFrameworks>
        <AssemblyName>DDS.Core.Commons.Annotations</AssemblyName>
        <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)</PackageId>
        <RootNamespace>DDS.Core.Commons.Annotations</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <PublicSign>true</PublicSign>
        <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
        <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I omitted some properties (description, author, etc) for brevity.

Do anyone has any idea on how the above can be accomplished now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As your project targets .NET Framework, you should probably disable PublicSign, as I indicated in https://blog.lextudio.com/tips-for-net-nuget-package-authors-august-2017-48f07604e4a0 Otherwise, .NET Framework projects might experience verification errors when consuming it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your .csproj. This tells the SDK to not reference NETStandard.Library or Microsoft.NETCore.App implicitly.